# Hiding unused tables - Must declare scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run a script that will hide all unused tables in the database using the following but it says Must declare the scalar variable "@TableName". The query part works and it retrieves all the right tables but it won't execute the command in the cursor loop.

```
use whatifdb
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND p.rows = 0
ORDER BY 
    t.Name

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN


    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'dbo',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = @TableName;
GO
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2008